# Is "Busen" just the area between the breasts?

Tags: meaning

I thought "der Busen" meant breasts. But then I heard someone knowledgeable claim it was just the area between the breasts.
I didn't understand all he said and it would have been too awkward for me to ask him.

Here's an illustration:

[image: Aphrodite of Milos]

<sub>Attribution: SpirosK photography from Athens, Greece [CC BY-SA 2.0 (https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)]</sub> <sub>Link: [Aphrodite of Milos](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Louvre_Museum_-_Aphrodite_of_Milos_(%CE%91%CF%86%CF%81%CE%BF%CE%B4%CE%AF%CF%84%CE%B7_%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%82_%CE%9C%CE%AE%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%85)_(7649039846).jpg)</sub>

**Does "Busen" denote the area between the breasts or the breasts?**

Comment: Hier https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/wortkunde/busen-etymologie.php ist ein kurzes, informatives Video zur Frage (ca. 90min.).

Comment: The original meaning is, I think, very close to the English equivalent *bosom.* The words have a common etymology if I can believe https://www.dwds.de/wb/Busen, coming from a West-Germanic root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *Busen* refers to terms we all agree on

1. the female breasts (Busen)
2. a bay (Meerbusen)

Then some you might have heard from

3. the human breast area in general (Brust)
4. the human inner breast where feelings arise
5. the area between the (female) breasts

And some you might have never heard from

6. a fold in the upper part of clothing (Falte im Oberteil eines Gewandes) used for transportation or storing personal items - there are a lot of examples in the bible
7. shirt collar (Hemdkragen)
8. lap, in the meaning of the area on top of the thighs of a sitting person (Schoß)

Just to name a few.

---

All of these definitions can be found in the [Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob Grimm und Wilhelm Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GB13460#XGB13460). But it says nothing about 5. the area between the (female) breasts. Can we say *Busen* doesn't denote the area between the breasts?

---

Let's take a deeper look.

One way is to look for historic examples where someone refers to the area between the breasts as *Busen*.

> [...] und gab es dem Weib, so wie ich auch die übrigen [Eier], die ich sorgfältiger geöffnet hatte, meinen übrigen Mägden gab, sie in ihren Busen zwischen den Brüsten bis zur Zeit des Ausschliesens zu erwärmen.

source: [Der Römisch-Kaiserlichen Akademie der Naturforscher auserlesene medizinisch-chirurgisch-anatomisch-chymisch- und botanische Abhandlungen, Band 20](https://books.google.de/books?id=tHRPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=%22busen%22%20anatomisch&source=bl&ots=HjkO_4ZuHg&sig=ACfU3U2XDppvzVkEVN5-a66jUxA6e-aeFQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQqa3qyvfiAhVDEVAKHdmoDmA4HhDoATAIegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%22busen%22%20anatomisch&f=false) from 1771

Will it be so easy? Unfortunately I don't think so. I'm pretty sure the author refers to 6. a fold in the upper part of your clothing, where he told his maiden to put the eggs, so they are warm and can hatch.

---

Ok next, at least there is one thing we can say so far: Anatomists **do say** Busen, when they are refering to the area between the female breasts, as anatomists Helmut Wicht is quoted in this [blog entry](https://scilogs.spektrum.de/sprachlog/der-mythos-vom-tal-zwischen-den-br-sten/) and there are [a](https://brockhaus.de/ecs/enzy/article/busen-anatomie) [lot](http://vmrz0100.vm.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/spomedial/content/e866/e2442/e9012/e9017/e9068/index_ger.html) [of](https://www.netdoktor.de/anatomie/brust/) [other](https://www.medizin-lexikon.de/Sinus) online dictionaries, where we can find this.

Anatomists call the area between the female breasts

> Sinus mammarum (old)
>
> Sinus intermammarius
>
> Sulcus intermammarius

or sometimes just short

> Sinus
>
> Sulcus

where Sinus can be translated as

> Bauch, Tasche, Bucht (paunche/bulge, pocket, bay)

and Sulcus as

> Rille (groove)

But OMG! Wait a minute and let's go back to Grimm's Wörterbuch. Right there ... in the very first line

> **busen, m. sinus**, κόλπος, sl. nadro, njedra, ahd. puosum (Graff 3, 218)

Is Busen for the area between the female breasts no more than a direct translation of the latin word *Sinus*, which is short for Sinus intermammarius/mammarum the anatomical name for the area between the female breasts? It makes sense.

Also, Helmut Wicht assumes, that it all started with the book *[Die alten deutschen Kunstwörter der Anatomie](https://digi.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/diglit/hyrtl1884)*, because it's the root for a lot of *Eindeutschungen*. But I'm not sure about it, but take a [look for yourself](https://digi.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/diglit/hyrtl1884/0057/image). But if it is true and the new meaning established around 1890 it wouldn't be found in the (earlier) *Grimm's Wörterbuch*.

---

#### Conclusion:

I think it's perfectly fine to say that the word *Busen* is referring to the area between the female breasts and no one will doubt it refers also to the female breasts. And even if I'm wrong with this derivation, anatomists are saying it anyway.

**Fun fact**: According to Grimm's DWB when talking about breasts *Busen* always refers to **both breasts** and the plural *Busen* refers to the breasts of multiple women.

Answer (score 33):

According to [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busen) it can mean both things.

1. Die zwei Brüste des Menschen werden auch als Busen bezeichnet.

or

2. Die Bucht oder Rinne zwischen den beiden Brüsten heißt Busen;

But especially in daily use I would assume most people use it as the first definition.
German is my mothertongue and I honestly did not know about the second definition.

Comment: I still have problems to accept Wikipedia as a quotable source... at least as long there are better sources available. That's because Wikipedia entries are multi-authored and especially fluid.

Comment: I have some trouble with that first definition. I am reasonably sure that, without any qualification or *really obvious* context, almost everybody I know would not interpret "Busen" to mean "a human's breast" and certainly not "a man's breast", but almost exclusively a "woman's breast".

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's just because we rarely talk about man's breasts in comparison^^

Comment: AFAIK the latter definition is the old one, for example Goethe's Letters mention it with the second  definition in mind. Modern speakers would immediately assume the prior one. (And be surprised if you talked about a man's "busen" as Goethe did

Comment: **Notice:** The Wikipedia entry was changed yesterday. The second definition was removed.

Comment: For me it is still the same Björn Friedrich

Comment: @SerenaT previously: *"die weibliche Brust als Ganzes oder die Vertiefung zwischen den Brüsten einer Frau"*; since June 18th: *"die weibliche Brust, in der Regel als Ganzes; veraltend auch die männliche Brust als Ganzes"*

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich the wiki entry was changed by Peter A. Schneider because of this thread and what he looked up, as he explains in his answer below. Another reason not to "trust" wikipedia in general, as it's still not clear if his changes are really right.

Comment: A more athorative source might be [der Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Busen)

Comment: @mtwde My favorite defense when I quote wikipedia is "of course it is correct, I have written is just yesterday!" No, seriously, wikipedia is very good -- often better than sources with better reputation, not least because it is often very up-to-date; but it is not authoritative. Notably though this particular dissent is debated between the scholars themselves -- the  linguists dissing each other with a vengeance I have last encountered when somebody cast the return value of `malloc()` in C. If *that* is the level of residual unreliability it's pretty good.

Comment: @mtwde By the way, informed by the contributions in answers, comments and links to this question I have re-added the "cleavage" meaning in wikipedia (the anatomical meaning actually has an entry in Brockhaus which I consider authoritative enough). All of the edits are still pending.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider wikipedia has its strengths and its flaws. And sometimes its strengths are its flaws. Wikipedia is a good source, but has limitations. Just as Christian wrote in his comment above. But that's more of a meta discussion, so let's get back to business.

Answer (score 31):

The usage of the word has changed over time.

These days, it usually means the female breast.

About 200 years ago, it was also used not for the area between the breasts, but also for the inside, the chest or rib-cage area.

This [poem](http://www.gedichtsuche.de/gedicht/items/Belsatzar%20-%20Heine,%20Heinrich.html) by Heinrich Heine contains the lines

> Dem König wards heimlich im **Busen** bang.

This is about a king, and he starts to feel fear. As he is a man, it doesn't refer to the breasts, and also not to the area between the breasts.

Comment: Also in other older poems and books they sometimes refer to the 'busen' also for males.

Comment: _Selig, wer sich vor der Welt / Ohne Hass verschließt, / Einen Freund am Busen hält / Und mit ihm genießt. / Was von Menschen nicht gewusst, / Oder nicht bedacht, / Durch das Labyrinth der Brust / Wandelt in der Nacht._ Goethe's poem _An den Mond_ is also clearly about a man's breast here.

Answer (score 21):

- **The word is, as far as I can see, almost completely equivalent with the English *bosom.*** Both come from a [West-Germanic root.](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Busen) Both can mean *female breasts*, ["especially as a single feature"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bosom), as Merriam-Webster succinctly puts it ("sie hat einen schönen Busen", meaning both breasts), as well as *male or female chest*.
- **The contemporary meaning in German is, in my experience, shifting towards being a synonym for the female breasts.** The old usage (e.g. a male speaker exclaiming to an old friend "Komm an meinen Busen!")  sounds funny to me and would likely be used as an ironic exaggeration only.

  As always with old words there is a certain gap between poetic, formal or generally high-level language on one side and casual everyday use on the other. In casual language I think the word is used exclusively as a synonym for "female breast", even in separation. For example it would not sound immediately wrong to me (as it did for the Grimm brothers as quoted in [Michael Hoppe's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/52789/6015)) if  one said "ihr linker Busen ist größer als ihr rechter".
- Answering and discussing the question I learned that **indeed in anatomy the gap between (probably female) breasts can be called *Busen,*** in a translation of *sinus [mammarum]* (see e.g. an entry in the [Brockhaus](https://brockhaus.de/ecs/enzy/article/busen-anatomie)). The background is perhaps that the *sinus* in the abstract sense is a curve which can go both ways; *Meerbusen* also is a translation of *sinus*, *sinus maritimus.*

I initially went and removed the "gap" meaning from the wikipedia page which initiated this discussion; but as I said I found several dictionary entries supporting that meaning in an anatomical context and now re-added the "cleavage* meaning on the wikipedia page. All edits are still pending. Sorry about all the work for the reviewers, whoever they are.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best answer so far.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Thank you. I always try. ;-).

Comment: There is a follow up [blog entry](https://scilogs.spektrum.de/sprachlog/der-mythos-vom-tal-zwischen-den-br-sten/) by him 6 months later where he goes deeper and concludes "Die „Ursprungsbedeutung“ von Busen ist einfach nur „Brust“, aber der Weg, auf dem das Wort in der Allgemeinsprache zu einem Wort für die weiblichen Brüste und in der Anatomie zu einem Fachbegriff für den Bereich zwischen den Brüsten geworden ist, wäre allemal spannend genug für die Rückseite einer Cornflakespackung. "

Comment: @mtwde Interesting, thanks. For what it's worth, I have started a collection of arguments for and against the "cleavage theory" on the [talk page of the wikipedia.de *Begriffsklärung* for *Busen*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskussion:Busen) in order to provide arguments for my still pending edit of that page (I eliminated the "cleavage" meaning which started this silly discussion). It is, after all, an enjoyable topic.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider The 2nd entry quotes anatomist Helmut Wicht, that while Busen is no official term it's often used by anatomists (today) when talking about the Sulcus inntermammarius. So the word has established itself and you shouldn't eleminate it. Also Grimms Wörterbuch can't know the meaning, as it presumably developed around 1900.

Comment: @mtwde I see. Brockhaus actually also lists the meaning, so I re-added it (with "anatomisch" as a qualifier).

Comment: @mtwde Btw, I indeed think this is an example how Latin often considers things we perceive as opposites as two sides of a coin; and synthesizes them in a single word: altus (high/deep), fides (loyalty/trust), and here sinus (convex/concave curve). So [*sinus*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sinus#Latin) can apparently be both, a bosom and the gap between the breasts.

Comment: Nie "Dieses Kleid betont ihren Busen/ihr Dekolletee" gehört?

Comment: @userunknown Both sounds possible, sure. I would contend that the sentences have different meanings (e.g., a garment with zero decolletee can emphasize the bosom). And please don't start an in-depth discussion of decolletee -- suffice it to say that "betont ihren Busen" in my book refers to protrusions ("as a single feature").

Comment: The *sinuses* "Nasennebenhölen" are clearly no protrusion. @PeterASchneider in Sapir-Whorff'ian manner I can't imagine how *altus* would express both at the same time, without learning it, though it would resolve the joke "I'm not affraid of heights, it's the depths*, whereas "not affraid of falling, but of the impact* gives it another twist. Anyhow, etymology shows many counter intuitive developments. The root PIE \*bhew- "to swell" seems pretty clearly on topic, though.

Comment: @vectory Hm, especially *altus* I always found almost scientific in its abstraction. It simply denotes a *difference in altitude.* Whether we behold it from above or below does not change a thing about a cliff's properties. It's very *altus.* If we want to wax psychological we could speculate that *altus* is an objective property of a physical reality while *high* or *deep* are *perceptions of a subject,* and take that as hints about how respective individuals perceived the world and their role in it. It resembles the concept of *acceleration* in physics which includes slowing down.

Comment: That doesn't explain the implicit question if *Busen* "tits" were taken from a narrow or opposite sense and how *sinus* relates. For [\*bʰuH-](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/bʰuH-) "(perfective) to grow, become, appear" (also given as \*bʰewH- "to swell, curve, bend" which may be dated) see [\*bʰewgʰ-](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/bʰewgʰ-) "to bend; curve, swelling"; One gives e.g. *to be*, its alternative *bosom*, and the second one *biegen, Armbeuge*. Cp. *bewegen; Bug, Buckel, Bügel; Berg, verbergen*; *bhogus "arm"?

Comment: @vectory I think these questions are beyond the scope of the OP, which was "Does "Busen" denote the area between the breasts or the breasts?". Note the present tense ;-). The answer is "usually the breasts, and only rarely, in anatomy, the gap between them."

Answer (score 13):

The noun [*Busen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Busen) is generally a synonyme of *weibliche Brust* (female breast).

I have only learned now, while doing research for this answer on [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busen), that *Busen* may also be used for the depression between the two female breasts. Unfortunately, Wikipedia remains silent about the origin of this usage. Other sources, such as the [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Busen) and [Duden Online](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Busen), do not know this meaning.

---

**Edit:** Notice that the Wikipedia entry was [changed](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Busen&oldid=185162879&diff=cur) on June 18<sup>th</sup> 2019. The definition that *Busen* may also be the depression between the breasts was exchanged with the definition that it used to be also referring to the male breast.

Comment: From skimming [this SciLogs article](https://scilogs.spektrum.de/sprachlog/der-mythos-vom-tal-zwischen-den-br-sten/) it looks like this: "Busen" originally meant "breast" in general, not just female. Over time, it got additionally established as a medical / anatomical term for the Sulcus intermammarius (the valley between the female breasts). Now, every now and then somebody has heard about that technical term and thinks they know the "proper" meaning of "Busen". But I don't have time to delve deeper into that right now.

Comment: @Hobbamok Kann es sein, dass Sie hier irgendwas missverstehen? Ich habe Wikipedia zitiert und dazu geschrieben, dass ich selbst das, was da (bis gestern) stand, noch nie gehört habe und dass ich bei anderen Quellen keinen Beleg dafür gefunden habe. Jetzt stellen Sie es so dar, als wäre das mit der "depression" meine eigene Meinung, die man widerlegen müsse??? Im Gegenteil, ich bin eher bei der Definition die Sie ja auch anführen. Also kein Grund mich mit schroffen Worten zurechtweisen zu wollen ...

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Interesting that you can see my pending wikipedia edit -- when I logged in from a different machine without my wikipedia account I could only see it when I looked at the editing history. Just out of curiosity -- is that a feature of logged-in users, i.e. were you logged in when you could see it? Btw, it's obviously good that there is some review mechanism; after all, after my edit this Austrian medical dictionary surfaced which indeed lists this obscure entry. I still think it's correct to edit it out though, all the more on a short *Begriffsklärungsseite,* it's obscure.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Wikipedia zeigt nicht angemeldeten Nutzern standardmässig die zuletzt von einem Nutzer mit Sichterrechten gesichtete Version an. Ein Benutzer mit Account kann es in seinen Einstellungen so konfigurieren, daß er immer die neueste Version angezeigt bekommt.

Answer (score 9):

A word where you can still see "Busen" referring to something with a concave shape is "Meerbusen" (= "sea bosom") which just means a big bay.

Comment: Als Meerbusen, aber nicht als Busen, oder?

Comment: @userunknown Der Jadebusen is the Jade Bay/Bight. At least it isn't explicitly der "Jademeerbusen"...

Comment: It's not quite clear to me whether a bay is concave -- some of the land is missing -- and thus supporting the cleavage theory; or whether it is convex -- the sea is protruding. I suppose it depends on the point of view. The Latin word for bay, [*sinus,*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sinus#Noun_8) is basically a curve and afaics can be concave (cavity) *or* convex (bosom), in good Latin tradition (*altus* -- high/deep, *fides* -- loyalty/trust) which makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek: Und die Touristen, sagen die, wenn sie zum Jadebusen spazieren wollen "Auf gehts, zum Busen!"? Oder sagen sie "Jadebusen/Meerbusen"?

Comment: @UserUnknown wenn Sie das wegen Tabuisierung nicht tun sollten, wäre das für die klinisch sterile Wissenschaft recht unerheblich, denn das Wort lässt sich einfach in seine zwei Hauptbestandteile zerlegen. Zumindest aus der Sicht wäre der Busen des Meeres, nicht der Küste gemeint, was aber kein Beweis ist. Dann stellt sich die Frage, ob die Küste eigentlich die Linie zwischen Wasser und Land ist, oder ob ein Meer ohne Küste sinnvoll erscheint.

Comment: @vectory: Ich widerspreche. Ob das Wort Busen auch für Meerbusen stehen kann ist eine Frage des Sprachgebrauchs, eine empirische, keine, die sich daran beantworten lässt, ob man das Wort zerlegen könnte. "Elfmeter" kann man auch zerlegen, aber nie sagt jmd. "Er hat den Meter verschossen". Außer Dir jetzt gleich, um mich Lügen zu strafen. :)

Comment: @UserUnknown ich verstehe nicht worauf das hinauslaufen soll, denn die Annahme, der Meer-Busen reflektiere das Wort Busen, ist unstrittig. Dass Meerbusen im Deutschen zusammengeschriebenwird, ist eine Eigenart die sich im Englischen bspw. kaum findet. So könnte man wohl auch *Meeres Busen* sagen, der Unterschied zu *Meeresbusen* ist dabei schlicht irrelefant.

Comment: @vectory scnr: Klar könnte man *des Meeres Busen* sagen; wie man überhaupt so manches sagen könnte. Im Falle des *Busens des Meeres* ist dieses "könnte" aber ein Irrealis, kein Potentialis, von Ausnahmen zum Zwecke der Demonstration mal abgesehen ;-). Da gebe ich unserem unbekannten Nutzer Recht.

Comment: Ja, wie PAS sagt. Ergänzend: Meerbusen (ohne Bindestrich) enthält das Wort Busen, es reflektiert das Wort nicht. Was sich im Englischen findet oder nicht findet ist völlig irrelevant hier. Mein Punkt ist, dass wenn jemand von einem Meerbusen spricht, er das nicht zu Busen verkürzt, wie man es oft tut, wenn man Netzstecker zu Stecker verkürzt, also auf die Frage des Threads bezogen ist, was Busen bedeutet, ist Meerbusen keine Antwort, zumindest keine richtige.

Answer (score 9):

"Busen" and "Brust" are quite different: "der weibliche busen, *doch nicht im sinne von mamma, uber; man kann nicht sagen* die milch im busen, dem kind den busen geben statt die brust; *gleich unstatthaft wäre* der rechte *oder* linke busen *für* die rechte *oder* linke brust."

from the Grimm Brothers, see http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GB13460#XGB13460

NB: "Heutzutage" wird mit "Busen" meist Anderes gemeint.  Als ich als Bub Märchen las, steckte sich oftmals jemand etwas in den Busen -- ich konnte mir beim Willen nicht vorstellen, wie das halten sollte ... Bis ich eben vor einigen Tagen im Grimm unter (3) las: "*das die (weibliche oder männliche) brust zwischen armen und hüften hüllende, sich darum biegende gewand*".  Endlich Klarheit nach fünfzig Jahren!

Comment: das deckt sich aber nicht mit kontemporärer nutzung.

Comment: @ErdincAy Ich möchte neben der Bemerkung von Björn Friedrich bezüglich der B-Note, der ich mich anschließe, inhaltlich folgendes zu bedenken geben: Die Wikipedia-Seite zur Begriffsklärung eines Wortes ist sicherlich keine Stelle für etymologische Erörterungen. Die aufgeführten Bedeutungen sollen sich vermutlich doch daran orientieren, was ein Benutzer vofinden kann. Das schließt sicherlich veraltete Bedeutungen ein, denn es werden ja auch alte Texte gelesen; aber völlig obsolete Bedeutungen gehören wohl eher nicht in die Liste.

Comment: Ich würde die Bedeutungen nicht *alt*, sondern vielmehr *ursprünglich* nennen.  Von wegen "alter" Bedeutung: wir wissen, "Kunst" kommt von "können" und "Vernunft" von "vernehmen", aber wer weiß -- ohne zu grimmen -- von welchem Verb "Macht" abstammt?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Und was will der Dichter uns nun sagen? ;-) Da die Bedeutungen nicht "alt" sind, soll man sie mit aufführen?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: Wie ermittelt man denn den Ursprung eines Wortes?

Comment: Der Ursprung eines Wortes kann ebensowenig "ermittelt", also "wissenschaftlich fassbar" gemacht werden wie bspw. der Beginn des Weinanbaus.  Schon Noah war ein Schwerenöter ...  Thomas Mann hat in der Vorrede zu *Joseph und seine Brüder*, der "Höllenfahrt", Aufschlussreiches darüber mitgeteilt.

Comment: @userunknown Bei manchen geht das ganz gut -- es gibt ja Neubildungen.

Comment: @PeterASchneider, ob ein Wort zur Sprache gehört, hängt von der Kategorisierung ab. Neuhochdeutsch beginnt ca. mitnLuther, schließt also eine ganze Menge Worte ein, die als *veraltet* zu kennzeichnen wären.

Comment: @userunknown In dem bereits von Dir selbst (es sei denn, ein zweiter Nutzer hatte die gleiche Namensidee) erwähnten [Video](https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/wortkunde/busen-etymologie.php) argumentiert Daniel Scholten bei etwa 1:28:10, dass man bei Wortneubildungen durchaus eine Ursprungsbedeutung feststellen kann, und kritisiert  Anatol Stefanowitsch heftig für die Behauptung des Gegenteils. Kommt mir vor, als genieße Daniel die Gegenrede.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Danke, für den Zeitstempel. Ja, ich habs verlinkt aber kenne natürlich nicht jedes Argument mehr auswendig. Was Etymologie betrifft, bin ich weitgehend unbeleckt. Auch schwirrt mir der Kopf schnell, wenn von mittelhochdt., ahd. germanisch, urgermanisch, urindog. usw. die Rede ist. Im Ggs. zum Navi sind Busen ja so alt wie der Mensch. Und soweit ich weiß sind schriftliche, germanische Dokumente aus Zeiten vor der römischen Invasion rar gesät. Auch ist mir unklar, wie man von Sinus auf Busen kommt.

Comment: @userunknown Videos für den Informationstransport über Sprache zu nutzen ist paradox (und deutet einen Hang zur Anbiederung an). -- Re Warum Sinus = Busen: Denk' den Sinus weniger als Bogen denn als *Wölbung!* Dann erscheint *Busen* sofort natürlich (und ist eine der direkten Übersetzungen von *sinus.*) Kann aber eben gut lateinisch *Aus-* oder *Ein*wölbung sein.

Comment: Ich kann deutsche Wörter bis in das Phönizische und "Arabische" (Babylonisch-Assyrische) zurückverfolgen, über gewisse Manipulationen oft über den Umweg über Latein. Das nennt man Wortmathematik oder Buchstabenmathematik. Beispielsweise das Wort "entwickeln" kommt ethmologisch aus dem Wort für "Das BLÜHEN einer Blume.". Das habe ich über das Englische Wort "develop", zu "blw" zu blühen zurückverfolgt. Die Einzelschritte sind über 6-7 Iterationen gegangen und ich musste mehrmals Buchstabenpositionen anpassen, und Buchstabensubstitutionen durchführen, um bis ins Phönizisch-Arabische zu gelangen.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: Die Form einer Sinuswelle ist mir geläufig. Wie aus dem Wort Sinus Busen geworden sein soll habe ich nicht verstanden. Dass Scholten Videos benutzt um Sprache zu erklären finde ich nicht im mindestens anbiedernd, sondern vielmehr durch die Art u. Weise, wie er Gebrauch davon macht, gerechtfertigt. Einerseits bleiben oft ältere Schritte oder Alternativen lange im Bild, so dass man eine Gedankenstütze hat. Dann werden spezielle Zeichen zur Aussprache oder Schreibweise gezeigt. Drittens liest er Zitate und Fremdsprachiges vor, u. man kann sich ein eigenes Bild machen.

Answer (score 1):

"Der Busen" (bosom) is generally the female "Brust" (breast) but in the whole, meaning both breasts. (Wikipedia)

Duden differentiates it from the female breast as following:

> Female breast in its vivid appearance especially in regards to its
>   erotic appeal.

Duden also indicates it as a synonym to the female breast or breasts but more in a poetic or antiquated way.

As a native speaker i would say, it simply means the whole female "breast area" but clearly not just the area between the breasts.

On the other hand, Wikipedia states in its article about "breast" that the area between two breasts is called "Busen". This is also describes in this [article](https://uni-24.de/brust-oder-busen-was-ist-der-unterschied-tz24/) (in German).

**But how come that this meaning is so unknown under German native speakers?**
 There is an interesting [article](https://scilogs.spektrum.de/sprachlog/der-mythos-vom-tal-zwischen-den-br-sten/) about this question (sorry, again German). Summary: It is the former or rather historical meaning.

The correct (or rather modern) name for the area between breaths is "Sulcus intermammarius" btw.

Answer (score 0):

> Does "Busen" denote the area between the breasts or the breasts?

As the question in a paradox reading implies (area between (the breasts or the breasts)) the answer is yes--which wouldn't happen with singular "the breast".

Whether the ridge gave a meronym, a subsense, of the more general whole, or vice-versa, is anyhow not part of the question, but still interesting to ask. I'm afraid I cannot decide it, and the thread so far is not completely clear either. The majority seems to think the word had always described *tits*.

Indeed, *-en* in most cases shows plural. *der Busen* would thus be a pluraletantum like *die Eltern*, and this point is driven further by the lack of a separate plural morpheme in *die Busen* (which would thus imply two peoples'bosoms). This is just a hint, not compelling evidence, as the English and German forms differ too much, which is expected for ever so slight taboo words. Further considerations would have little to do with modern German, so I will skip analogous  comparisons of *tit* and *zit*.

The question can be parsed as an inclusive or. In that sense, the chest bone area as the center of gravity of the bosom is the anatomical human chest more truly than the "milk bags" that *bosom* today generally refers to.

Comment: In (the breasts or the breasts) - wo liegt da der Unterschied? Ist einmal "breast" gemeint (Einzahl)? "In most cases plural" - das habe ich jetzt nicht nachgezählt, aber anhand der Mehrheit der Fälle kann man das wohl nicht vermuten (siehe Hoden, Magen, Wagen, Rasen, ...).